# Update two columns by another column of next row from same table in sql

Tags: sql-server

Here is my table
[image]

And my output should be
[image]

I want to update the `closed_date,time` for `new_class_desc ='FLM'` with next `Update_date,Update_time` but if `new_class_desc` is `'FollowupComments'` then ignore it and update the next date as `Closed_date`

I was trying query somewhat like this..

```
;WITH cte as(
  SELECT *
  ,row_number() OVER(ORDER BY Update_date,Update_time) rn 
  FROM Table 
  WHERE Problem_sid = 1435819
)
UPDATE c1 SET Closed_date = c2.Update_date, Closed_time = c2.Update_time
FROM cte c1 
JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn - 1 
   AND c1.New_class_desc = 'FLM' 
   AND c2.New_class_desc <> 'FLM'
   AND c2.New_class_desc  not  in ('FollowUpComments')
```

But  in this I am not getting `new_class_desc =Bank` update_date as `Closed_date` for  Flm.

Please guide here.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.Update_date, t.Update_time) AS  rno  
    FROM my_Table t 
    WHERE t.New_class_desc <> 'FollowUpComments'
)
UPDATE t
SET t.Closed_Date = t1.Closed_Date,
t.Closed_Time = t1.Closed_Time
FROM cte t 
JOIN cte t1 ON t.rno = t1.rno + 1 
WHERE t.New_class_desc = 'FLM'
```